# SQL How to find missing values in rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have a database and an external file. What these two share are reference codes for products.

But in the external file I have all my reference codes saved down, whilst plenty are still missing in the database. Is there a way to make a query so that I can check what values are missing in my database, in a given table?

There's no need to worry about how the XML interfaces with the database. I already have that down through PHP and simplexml. I am mostly struggling with the query to use in this case.

| Database | XML File |
| --- | --- |
| AJS2S | AJS2S |
| ABBB2 | ABBB2 |
|  | JJI90K |
|  | JJJJ92 |

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of valus at hand and you want to check which ones are missing in your table, you enumerate them in a `union all` subquery, then use `not exists`:

```
select x.product_code
from (
    select 'AJS2S' as product_code
    union all select 'ABBB2'
    union all ...
) x
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t where t.product_code = x.product_code)
```

Or, in very recent versions of MySQL (8.0.19 or higher), you can use the `values()` row constructor:

```
select x.product_code
from (values row('AJS2S'), row('ABBB2'), ...) x(product_code)
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t where t.product_code = x.product_code)
```

Of course, if you have your xml data already loaded in a table, say `xmltable`, then you can use that instead of the subquery:

```
select x.product_code
from xmltable x(product_code)
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t where t.product_code = x.product_code)
```

Comment: What I have is a foreach loop foreach($xml->Products->Product as $pro) which then creates an array $results[$counter] = array(
   'Code' => isset($pro->Code) ? (string)$pro->Code : false,

Said array is then indexed by the several attributes in the .xml file like this: $ref = $results[$counter]['Code'];

Is the third solution adaptable anyhow to work with this?

Comment: It's returning me endless 'falsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalse' when I run the php file instead of giving me the reference code missing in the database

Answer (score 1):

You would use `not exists`:

```
select code
from xml
where not exists (select 1 from database d where d.code = xml.code);
```

This retrieves each code -- so it might have many duplicates.  You can summarize using `group by`:

```
select code, count(*)
from xml
where not exists (select 1 from database d where d.code = xml.code)
group by code;
```

Comment: It's returning me endless 'falsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalse' when I run the php file instead of giving me the reference code missing in the database

Comment: @Haykne . . . Unless that is a code in the XML file, then such results would seem to indicate a problem querying the XML file